# Signal in Simulink with defined frequency content

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can i define a block in simulink which have uniform (or at least as uniform as possible) frequency content in a defined frequency range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Sine Wave block, and enter a vector of frequency values, this will give you a vector of sine waves each with one specific frequency, then sum the output of the block.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create the signal yourself starting from a random signal source. Random signal should have uniform frequency in all bands. Then use a filter to restrict this to your defined frequency range. You can design your filter using fdatool.